# Is Haruki Murakami considered fantasy/sci-fi?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is Haruki Murakami considered fantasy/sci-fi? [1Q84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1Q84) involves parallel worlds and the supernatural. [The Wind-up Bird Chronicle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wind-Up_Bird_Chronicle) also involves the supernatural and a dream reality. Would questions on these books be considered on topic for SFF.SE?

Comment: Downvoter: What does your downvote represent? Do you disagree that much of Murakami's work is on-topic, or that this is the right place to ask the question, or are there other issues with the question?

Comment: @user1030 - The downvote is probably because instead of asking for a ruling on a specific work, the question asks about the entire bibliography of an author.

Answer (score 6):

Both those and many of his other works fall squarely into the literary tradition of *magical realism*, which is usually considered to be sf. Some have additional links to the sf tradition, such as the parallel history in *1Q84* or the science fantasy elements in *Hard-Boiled Wonderland*.

His work has been reviewed often in genre publications.

You will find many of his works in the ISFDB.

Because closing is governed by community votes no one can promise genre-killing reactionaries won't close the question (and there are some on the site), but well, they're genre-killing reactionaries.